# Set precision with fstream to output file - format double

Tags: c++, double, precision, fstream

I cannot find an answer for how I might use an already opened fstream to output formatted doubles to a text file. Currently my code is doing this:

```
int writeToFile (fstream& f, product_record& p)
{
   if (!f){
      cout << "out file failed!!error" << endl;
      return -1;
   } else {

      f << p.idnumber << endl;
      f << p.name << endl;
      f << p.price << endl;
      f << p.number << endl;
      f << p.tax << endl;
      f << p.sANDh << endl;
      f << p.total << endl;
      f << intArrToString( p.stations ) << endl;

   }
}
```

Where p is struct called product_record and price, tax, sANDh, and total are all **doubles** I have tried doing `f << setprecision(4) << p.price << endl;` but this does not work. How can i format this double to have a precision of two decimal places. Like this `"#.00"`. How can I achieve this using specifically fstream?

Also, fyi, the overall task is to simply read a txt file, store data in a struct, add structs to a vector and then read from the structs to print to an output file. The input file already has the doubles formatted like 10.00, 2.00 and such(2-decimal places)

Comment: Okay my bad Ill type it out one sec.

Comment: `f << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);`

Comment: Please try providing constructive criticism before blatantly down voting for no reason. Thank you @user657267 I will try that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using

```cpp
#include <iomanip>  // std::setprecision()

f << std::fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;
```

`std::setprecision()` sets the number of significant digits, not the number of decimals places. For example

```cpp
cout << setprecision(3) << 12.3456 << endl;
```

would output 12.3
Sending in fixed first makes it so you are setting the precision from a fixed position (the decimal place) rather than from the first digit of the floating point value.

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you very much. I am still a bit confused as to why it would not work without `fixed`.