# Removing all decimals except for two

Tags: c++, double, decimal

I didn't want to write 'rounding' because rounding, as far as I know changes it. What I want:
I have a double that's, let's say equal to 1.56789, and I want to make it 1.56 without converting it to string and removing characters and such. Also, if I had a double 1.5 I want to make it 1.50.

Comment: 1.50 is the same as 1.5. What do you mean by *if I had a double 1.5 I want to make it 1.50*?

Comment: @R Sahu
What I mean is I'm doing a competition where all outputs, for this problem, have to be doubles with 2 decimal places, even if it's 1.5, they require an output of 1.50

Comment: Do you actually need to truncate the number or just how it is outputted?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029233/set-precision-with-fstream-to-output-file-format-double.

Comment: I actually only need it for the output